# Can Azure Event Hub be configured in a Pub/Sub fashion to another Event Hub without coding?

Tags: azure, publish-subscribe

We are looking to consume data from another Event hub not in our Tenant and want to ensure a guarantee delivery.  Can an Event Hub be configured to connect to another Event Hub without build an Azure Function, Databricks process or some other solution OOTB?

Today we are planning to setup the consumer Hub using either the HTTP or AMQP protocols and have the producer push via some code.

From what I have read Stream Analytics could do this but doesn't sound like it's reliable and would prefer to leverage a feature before building out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at [Azure Eventgrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview):

- It can ingest data from an Eventhub: [Azure Event Hubs as an Event Grid source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-event-hubs)
- It can send data to an EventHub: [Event hub as an event handler for Azure Event Grid events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-event-hubs)

It doesn't require coding but will still require configuration.